# how to execute a thread after completion of another thread?

Tags: c, linux, process, pthreads, kill

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
void *f1(void *p)
{
system("./while.exe");
}

main()
{
int i=0;
int k=3;
int j=0;
void *status
while(i<k)
{

    thread_id = pthread_create(&thread_handler, NULL, &f1,NULL);
 pthread_join(thread_pram_play_handler, &status);
//if(((int *)status)==0)
            i++;
}//while

while(1)
{
printf("\nEnte value ");
scanf("%d",&j);
if(j==1)
{
system("pkill while.exe");
}
} 
}
```

While.c contains:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<25;i++)
{
printf("\nHI");
}
}
```

Here, I am just writing a code similar to my actual code.
My requirements
1. I want to execute three threads one after the completion of another.
2. I want to terminate it in between using pkill.

Using pthread_join I am able to execute threads one after another but I am not able to kill.

If I am not using pthread_join then threads are executing simultaneously and able to kill them.I think it is blocking the process.

I am not able to fulfill my requirements. So either I have to change thread execution way or have to change the way of terminating a thread.

Thank you

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The code as shown won't compile. This is not nice.

Comment: Also the code it is badly formatted, which makes it difficult to read. This isn't nice as well.

Comment: Even more it should at least be `int main(void)`.

Comment: This code is completely similar to my actual code. My actual code contains many related files and it will be big so just to convey my question well. I wrote this program.

Comment: "*so just to convey my question well. I wrote this program.*" this is the right approach, yes, if the code would compile.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to execute three threads one after the completion of another.

Then you don't need threads at all. That requirement defeats the purpose of multi-threading.

> If I am not using pthread_join then threads are executing simultaneously and able to kill them.I think it is blocking the process.

Yes, since the main thread is blocked at `pthread_join()` (waits for the completion of the created using `pthread_create()`), it doesn't get a chance to execute your `pkill` command. `system()` blocks the until the command is completed which in turn blocks the main thread which is waiting at `pthread_join()`.

Basically your two requirements contradict each other. The closest thing you can do is to run the "command" in background with `&`:

```
system("./while.exe &");
```

so that `system()` returns immediately and the main thread can continue and able to run the `pkill` command. But this approach would fulfill your your requirements, it doesn't make a lot of sense in practical programming.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I tried as you said but all the threads are executing at the same time. Is there any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Threads are supposed to run simultaneously ;-) I don't understand why you have such requirements. Besides system() would fork & exec the command. `fork()` in multi-threaded program can be tricky: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Answer (score 0):

Put the body of the killer-while-loop into another thread function and start it as a separate thread right before you start the `f1`-thread.

Wait for both threads to join and start over.